# Операторы и операнды

Tags: c++

Необходимо посчитать количество уникальных операторов и операнд и сколько всего операторов и операнд в коде.
Есть какаянить прога или сайт, которые это автоматически сделают?

Comment: К сожалению помочь с этим вопросом не могу, но разбирает любопытство. А какую задачу можно решить при помощи таких подсчетов? Где можно практически и с пользой это применить?

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понимаю зачем тебе это(Скорее всего я не понял вопрос), но ты можешь попытаться сделать автоген документации [Doxygen](https://caiorss.github.io/C-Cpp-Notes/Doxygen-documentation.html)

 И из него посчитать количество операторов и операнд

---

Если это не то, то напиши регулярку для поиска операторов и операнд [egex101.com](https://regex101.com/)